# Use of in a state of being

Tags: phrase-usage

> A tooth extracted from a human was delivered in a state of being soaked.

Would it be correct if I say phrases below instead of in a state of being soaked?

> A tooth extracted from a human was delivered in a state of that is soaked.
>
> A tooth extracted from a human was delivered in a condition that is soaked

Comment: The sequence [*(something) was delivered **soaking wet***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+delivered+soaking+wet%22) occurs a couple of times in Google Books, but there's no place for ***in a state of being*** in such contexts. And I must just say that "a tooth extracted from a human" is an exceptionally weird context that doesn't offer much hope of finding a "natural" way to include it in any relevant examples

Comment: "To [soak](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soak)" is "to penetrate or permeate by saturation", "to be saturated with liquid", etc. Teeth don't absorb liquid so "a soaked tooth" doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of your suggestions works, I'm afraid.

"In a state of that is soaked" is not grammatical.

If you remove "of" you get "in a state that is soaked". That is grammatical, and sort-of meaningful, but logically it says that the state is soaked, not that the tooth is soaked. Sometimes we say things that don't work logically, but this is not one of them: "in a state that is soaked" is not natural.

The same points apply to "in a condition that is soaked", except that, to my ear, this is not as bad as with "state". I'm not sure why.

I would probably say

> A tooth extracted from a human was delivered soaked.

but if you want "state" or "condition" in, then *in a soaked state/condition* seems best to me.